# Работы с директорий, которая выше уровнем

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток Друзья!
Есть необходимость работать с директорией, которая на несколько уровней выше, чем та, в которой лежит мой скрипт. Посмотрите, вот такая структура папок будет :

[image]

Из папки **file_manager**, нужно будет увидеть всё содержимое папки **take_test**, она же и будет корнем, адрес корневой директории из папки **file_manager** будет **"../../../../"**. И следовательно вопрос : Можно ли, а точнее есть ли такая функция в **php** на подобии **"cd:"**, чтобы "выбрать" каталог для работы, и уже обращаться к его содержимому относительно, например так : **./setup/** или **./system/cache_controll**.

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Chroot не реализована для windows, остаётся chdir для "кросс платформенного" использования я так понимаю, первая функция от второй отличаются, только работой на платформах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не пробовал `chroot` и `chdir` и . ..?

**Добавлено.**

Не только этим. Вот справка: изменяет корневой каталог текущего процесса на переданный в качестве параметра `str`. Возвращает `TRUE` в случае успешного завершения, `FALSE` в случае возникновения ошибки.

Данная функция доступна только в том случае, если ее поддерживает ваша операционная система и вы используете методы вызова CLI, CGI или Embed SAPI.